# Resharper no warning for "parameter never used"

Tags: c#, resharper

I wonder why resharper doesn't produce warnings of type "parameter 'aaa' is never used" for un-used method arguments of public methods:

[image]

If you configure resharper to perform "solution wide analysis", then the warning is displayed on both private and public methods:

[image]

Any idea about the reason? Is it a bug?

Comment: Probably because without solution-wide analysis ReSharper cannot claim that the public method is not called in other assembly with this parameter specified?

Comment: @Andrei: but it is not about the use of the method but the unused parameter with the name `unused`. So it doesn't matter if this method is used or not. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/Parameter+%27Name%27+is+never+used

Comment: Even it is not used in current solution, it it may be used in another solution.  I think, that's why Resharper does not mark it as unused by default.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I doubt that. ReSharper should be smart enough not to suggest to remove something that could potentially cause compiling errors. Also, imagine the call `Do2("some string")`. Would you say parameter is being used here? I would

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, it does matter.  Even if the parameter isn't used, removing it would be a breaking change, so removing it is very likely not *possible*.  There's not much point in pointing out a problem that can't actually be fixed.

Comment: @Andrei: if it caused a compiler error everything is fine because you get the error immediately and you know what to fix(either the calling code or the method). I thought resharper was a tool that is supposed to help you to find redundant things. If i provide a parameter in a method and that method is already used everywhere but the parameter is never used, shouldn't resharper tell me that?

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's a tool to help you refactor code.  Creating errors is not a valid refactor.

Comment: @Servy: but maybe the calling code needs to be fixed because it uses an overload of this method that should not exist. Then it would be nice to know that those methods don't need that parameter as soon as poosible(to fix less code). If i remove the parameter the compiler tells me exactly which parts i have to fix.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That's assuming the calling code can even be changed at all.  If it's part of the public API of a class library, there's a very strong chance that it's *not* possible.  When resharper *can* determine that all uses of the method are in code that it can edit, then it does trigger the warning.

Comment: @Servy: it's more likely that **your** method is used by **your** code than that it's used in public code that is not under your control. So isn't it  reasonable to assume that it can be changed? If not you can ignore that warning anyway.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Whether the code is in scope based on resharper's settings is what determines that though.  When the scope of the search is such that resharper can determine that you do in fact control all uses of it, it mentions it.  When it can't, it doesn't.  The warning, or lack of it, is very specifically dependent on whether or not it's accessible from external code you don't control.  Also keep in mind that when your refactor suggestions start suggesting changes that cause *major* problems it makes the tools *far* less useful.  They need to be conservative in their suggested refactors.

Comment: @TimSchmelter When refactor tools have a very high false positive rate by constantly suggesting refactors that aren't valid, it makes them *far* less useful.  It makes finding the useful points among the noise a lot harder, it removes trust in the tool, and you of course need to realize that not everyone using the tool will have an intimate understanding of when the proposed refactors will and won't be valid, if they're not always valid.

Comment: Remark: in the second case (solution wide analysis enabled) the warning remains even if the public method is called somewhere in the solution: so it means that this warning is indeed only related to the body of the method (as @Andrei said). In "Solution wide analysis", resharper doesn't take care of calls to this method, so why should resharper do it if the "solution wide analysis" is disabled?

Answer (score 2):

Removing a parameter from a method is a breaking change, and as such a parameter can't just be removed simply because it's not being used currently.  For a `private` method the only scope that needs to be looked at is the class in question.  When the method is public the tool can't necessarily know if it's actually possible to remove the parameter.  If it can look through the entirety of the scope it can determine if the method is actually used outside of the class, and thus determine whether refactoring the method is feasible.

Comment: But why does it matter if this method is used at all? The warning should tell you that the parameter seems to be useless. So even if some code calls this method with that parameter it might be  a bug because the parameter isn't used.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It matters because if the method is used, then removing the parameter is going to break all of the code using the method.  Turning a compiling solution into one that doesn't compile is not a valid refactor, so it's not suggested.

Comment: In the second case (solution wide analysis enabled) the warning remains even if the public method is called somewhere in the solution: so it means that this warning is only related to the body of the method (as @Andrei said above). In "Solution wide analysis", resharper doesn't take care of calls to this method, so why should resharper do it if the "solution wide analysis" is disabled?

Comment: @jeromerg "solution wide" essentially mean "R#, this is self-contained set of classes" - so R# now can safely assume that if parameter is not used then solution-wide refactoring will not break any code that depends on the method (because you essentially instructed R# that there is no other calling code). Details can be found in [R# Solution-wide analysis](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Code_Analysis__Solution-Wide_Analysis.html)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Good point! With this in mind, I can understand the reason why resharper discerns both cases!

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I would accept your explanation as the correct answer, as it sounds really consistent! (even if the result is somehow weird, to the point of view of the developer coding the body of the method)

Comment: @jeromerg I think it is already covered in last sentence of this answer: " If it(R#) can look through the entirety of the scope...". I'll post separate answer later if Servy is not updated this question by than. You may also want to ask separate question (link to this one) on "what solution wide in R# means" if it is not yet covered in documentation/existing answers.

Comment: Personnally, I would prefer if resharper would warns in all cases. And let the analysis of potential breaking changes to tools that can really do it, like NDepend, LibCheck or custom implementation

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Amazingly: resharper proposes in both analysis mode the renaming of method arguments of public methods... which is a breaking change. So, R# doesn't systematically preserve the public API when the "solution wide analysis" is disabled... ;-)

Comment: @Servy the explanation you are giving for the reason why resharper does not offer this most obvious and most useful warning does not hold any water. Resharper is capable of doing all sorts of refactorings that break code, so the ability to break code is never a reason to prohibit a refactoring.  Also, the entire discussion about refactorings is irrelevant here: we are speaking about the valid need to see a warning, and whether we will refactor or not as a result of seeing the warning is a different story.  But we do need to see the warning.

Comment: @MikeNakis The warning wouldn't be *correct*, so it obviously wouldn't be "useful and obvious".  The warning simply *doesn't apply*.  I haven't argued that it shouldn't perform some explicit refactor request due to it being a breaking change, I'm simply saying it's not going to tell you something is unused when *it cannot make such a determination*.

Comment: The determination can be made by simply analyzing the body of the function and realizing that the parameter is unused.

Comment: Unfortunately JetBrains also fails to understand the need for this warning. Here is the relevant ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-202491/Unused-Parameter-inspection